# Pentaho CE 9.1 - Error "This page can't be displayed" when selecting file *.ktr

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration (Version CE 9.1) on Windows Server 2016.
Whenever I select a local transformation file, Pentaho only shows error message "This page can't be displayed. Make sure the web address http://127.0.0.1:9053 is correct".

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6zzA.png)

By reading Pentaho's log file, I found this error log "ERROR [HttpServiceStarted] Could not start the servlet context for context path [] java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:9052"

I tried to delete all Pentaho's cache files and disable all network adapter. However, it's hopeless.

Is there anything else I can configure to overcome this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Disable intel graphics command center service]

Disable intel graphics command center service